# Run python class only once and save output for later use

Tags: python, selenium, oop, web-scraping

So I have this craigslist scraper project I am working on and I am running into a potential problem. I have this file url.py that has a UrlObj class and getters and setters. In my main.py, I am instantiating that object and getting the completed url back to be sent to the Job class in my main.py to do its scraping stuff.

I would like to deploy this in the cloud in the future and have it run on a time interval (i.e. every day, 4 hours, etc), but I have noticed a problem. Every time this program is ran, the UrlObj class will be called, prompting the user to enter the relevant data to construct the URL. Since this will be in the cloud running in the background, no one will be able to input the prompts every time its built and ran.

What I want is for url.py and UrlObj to be called only once, in the beginning to allow the user to input and populate the necessary fields to construct the url. Then, every time the program is built and ran, the url the user made in the beginning should be used, not calling url.py and UrlObj to prompt the user again to type in inputs since it will be running in the cloud and on a time interval.

Is it too naive to think to set conditions around `url = UrlObj().url` to make sure it runs once. Like an if statement or while loop?

url.py:

```
class UrlObj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.location = self.get_location()  # Location(i.e. City) being searched
        self.postal_code = self.get_postal_code()  # Postal code of location being searched
        self.query = self.get_query()  # Search for the type of items that will be searched
        self.max_price = self.get_max_price()  # Max price of the items that will be searched
        self.radius = self.get_radius()  # Radius of the area searched derived from the postal code given previously

        self.url = f"https://{self.location}.craigslist.org/search/sss?&max_price={self.max_price}&postal={self.postal_code}&query={self.query}&20card&search_distance={self.radius}"

    def get_location(self):
        location = input("Please enter the location: ")
        return location

    def get_postal_code(self):
        postal_code = input("Please enter the postal code: ")
        return postal_code

    def get_query(self):
        query = input("Please enter the item: ")
        return query

    def get_max_price(self):
        max_price = input("Please enter the max price: ")
        return max_price

    def get_radius(self):
        radius = input("Please enter the radius: ")
        return radius
```

main.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
from url import *


class Job():

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Program Files\chromedriver")  # Path of Chrome web driver
        self.delay = 5  # The delay the driver gives when loading the web page

    # Load up the web page
    # Gets all relevant data on the page
    # Goes to next page until we are at the last page
    def load_craigslist_url(self, url):
        data = []
        self.driver.get(url)
        while True:
            try:
                wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.delay)
                wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "searchform")))
                data.append(self.extract_post_titles())
                WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchform"]/div[3]/div[3]/span[2]/a[3]'))).click()
            except:
                break
        return data

    # # Extracts all relevant information from the web-page and returns them as individual lists
    def extract_post_titles(self):
        all_posts = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("result-row")

        dates_list = []
        titles_list = []
        prices_list = []
        distance_list = []

        for post in all_posts:

            title = post.text.split("$")

            if title[0] == '':
                title = title[1]
            else:
                title = title[0]

            title = title.split("\n")
            price = title[0]
            title = title[-1]
            title = title.split(" ")
            month = title[0]
            day = title[1]
            title = ' '.join(title[2:])
            date = month + " " + day

            if not price[:1].isdigit():
                price = "0"
            int(price)

            raw_distance = post.find_element_by_class_name(
                'maptag').text
            distance = raw_distance[:-2]

            titles_list.append(title)
            prices_list.append(price)
            dates_list.append(date)
            distance_list.append(distance)

        return titles_list, prices_list, dates_list, distance_list

    # # Kills browser
    def kill(self):
        self.driver.close()

    @staticmethod
    def organizeResults(results):
        titles_list = results[0][0]
        prices_list = list(map(int, results[0][1]))
        dates_list = results[0][2]
        distance_list = list(map(float, results[0][3]))

        list_of_attributes = []

        for i in range(len(titles_list)):
            content = {'Listing': titles_list[i], 'Price': prices_list[i], 'Date posted': dates_list[i],
                       'Distance from zip': distance_list[i]}
            list_of_attributes.append(content)

        list_of_attributes.sort(key=lambda x: x['Distance from zip'])

        return list_of_attributes

    @staticmethod
    def to_csv(dictionary):
        df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
        df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # This should be called only once!!!
    # Then the 'url' should be used every time main.py is built and ran, and not be constructed again by calling 'UrlObj().url'
    url = UrlObj().url


    scraper = Job()
    results = scraper.load_craigslist_url(url)
    scraper.kill()
    dictionary_of_listings = scraper.organizeResults(results)
    scraper.to_csv(dictionary_of_listings)
```

Comment: Don't ask for the data in the class. Make that class into a `NamedTuple` or `dataclass` just to hold the data if you want, then ask for the data outside the class once, and save the data to file. Then, when run, if that file exists, don't ask for input again and just use the existing data.

Comment: I did what you suggested but with a twist. In the '__main__' there is a if not condition that checks if a url.txt file is present in the project folder. Of course, the first time this is ran there will not be one, so i make a url.txt file and write the url to it. Now out of that if not, i read the url from the url.txt file into a variable and pass it to my load_craifgslist_url() method and start scraping. It will scrape for how many times I want using that url without prompting the user to input it again.

Comment: ```if not path.exists('url.txt'):
        url = UrlObj().url
        text_file = open('url.txt', 'w')
        text_file.write(url)


    x = open('url.txt', 'r')
    y = x.read()
    scraper = Job()
    results = scraper.load_craigslist_url(y)
    scraper.kill()
    dictionary_of_listings = scraper.organizeResults(results)
    scraper.to_csv(dictionary_of_listings)```